# Recording whether my app has received a notification

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, apple-push-notifications

If the application is not running in the foreground then the OS will display an alert with the notification received for that application.

My  question is ..... whether it is possible for me to set some flag in device persistance or is there any way to make a note that my appliction has received notification ?

Beacuse later when the user launches the application (From springBoard and not by clicking 'View' button in push alert), i need to use the flag (whether some notifications received for this app) and has to make some server calls either to get the cached value or the server has to refresh it ... Since some notifications was received.

Answer (score 2):

No, the information of push notification received and not readed is lost, but you can look the badge value if you increment it with each notification.

Comment: Just to add to this, you could also just set the badge count to "1" with any notification and then clear when you open the app again - figuring out a correct incremental number to end with each push might be rather tricky, and just setting it to "1" each time treats the badge as a flag that says "go update".